# Large double mathematical multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, double, double-precision

I want to multiply this number:

> 5374711027510012111075768211110475111691021051041057653548210911210211112250867
>   66690120741165250567278571217510410482757487

with this number:

> 4956889911565576581818287977011111065876967103548749122901151091038910610511189

But when I cast the result to string I get this:

> 2.66418508698446E+201

Which is:

> 266418508698446000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   0000000000000000000000000000000

Not exactly the precise number, those zeros represent loss of precision, am I right?

Is it possible to get the precise number (every single digit) out of this calculation using C#?

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at [BigInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)?

Comment: @hometoast: Not a duplicate of that at all. That's a language-agnostic question about  *implementing* a big integer data type, not about using one in a C#-specific Framework.

Comment: @Jason That may be what the question intended, but that's not what the answers are, and so its answers most certainly answer this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). It's *designed* for this purpose. The numbers you are using won't fit in the primitive integral and can't even be represented *precisely* in the floating-point types<sup>1</sup>.

```
BigInteger m = BigInteger.Parse("374711027510012111075768211110475111691021051041057653548210911210211112250867 66690120741165250567278571217510410482757487");
BigInteger n = BigInteger.Parse("4956889911565576581818287977011111065876967103548749122901151091038910610511189");
var product = m * n;
Console.WriteLine(proudct);
```

<sup>1</sup>: Single-precision floating point can represent all integers between -2^24 and 2^24 *exactly* because it has a 23-bit explicit plus one implicit bit mantissa; after that it loses precision. As

```
2^24 = (2^10)^2.4 ~ (10^3)^2.4 ~ 10^7
```

we lose precision for *some* integers *after* **approximately** seven digits.

Similarly, double-precision floating point can represent all integers between -2^53 and 2^53 *exactly* because it has a 52-bit explicit plus one implicit bit mantissa; after that it loses precision. As

```
2^53 = (2^10)^5.3 ~ (10^3)^5.3 ~ 10^16
```

we lose precision for *some* integers *after* **approximately** sixteen digits.

Answer (score 0):

A [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) has a limited maximum precision (number of significant digits) of 15. Your numbers have too many digits and thus cannot be stored as double without loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.5, make use of system.Numerics assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx

> var num1 = BigInteger.Parse("5374711027510012111075768211110475111" +
>                                              "69102105104105765354821091121021111225086766690120741165250567278571217510410482757487");
>
> var num2 =
>                   BigInteger.Parse("4956889911565576581818287977011111065876967103548749122901151091038910610511189");
>
> Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);